# Powershell: How to pass an argument with special characters?

Tags: powershell

I have this command `App.exe -S'Report Processing':'':0`  that works fine in cmd
I tried to run it with PowerShell, but this later ignores the simple quotes (it runs it like `App.exe -SReport Processing::0` )
How can I pass an argument that contains quotes in PowerShell?

Comment: If you don't need any of PowerShell's replacement behavior (i.e. no variables interpolated in the arguments) you can just use the stop-parsing symbol: `App.exe --% -S'Report Processing':'':0` to pass the arguments as-is.

Comment: Thank  you @JeroenMostert this is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The "Correct" way to run .exe tools in powershell is with `Start-Process`

```
Start-Process App.exe -ArgumentList "-S'Report Processing':'':0"
```

Though in your case, you can get away with simply enclosing the arguments in double-quotes:

```
App.exe "-S'Report Processing':'':0"
```

Comment: Using double quotes didn't work for me, although I think your answer is not wrong, but the comment of @Jeroen is right answer